# Material-UI pickers trigger validation on blur not on change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, onblur

As soon as you start typing inside the DatePicker component, the validation is triggered.

How does one trigger validation on blur instead of onInputChange when using

`@material-ui/pickers` meant for `material-ui v4`

Passing the value to the blur function should work and omitting on change, but as soon as you remove the onChange event the code breaks.

**Example**

```
export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState();

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    setSelectedDate(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        id="date-picker-dialog"
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

[Muiv4 documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/)

[Stackblitz example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cq00x?file=/demo.js:181-721)

Comment: This documentation says that `onChange` is required: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage
"Please note that all components are controlled, meaning that it's required to pass the `value` and `onChange` props."

Comment: @patrickb that's ok, let onChange fill the value... but can the validation be triggered on blur only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `onChange` is mandatory returning `undefined` in the callback solves the issue but breaks the datePicker select option (does not apply the selected date to the input field).

Because of the above, `onAccept` should be used thereby internal state logic can be omitted which is crucial.

Code

```
export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState();

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    setSelectedDate(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        id="date-picker-dialog"
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={()=>undefined}
        onAccept{setSelectedDate}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cq00x?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` is required, per the [documentation](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage). However, you don't need to set the `value` in `onChange`. If you omit the `setSelectedDate` in that function and instead only do it in `onBlur`, the date setting and validation will only occur with the `blur` event.

```js
export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState();
  const [wasOpened, setWasOpened] = React.useState();

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    if (wasOpened)
    {
      setSelectedDate(date);
    }
  };

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    setSelectedDate(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleOnOpen = () => {
    setWasOpened(true);
  };

  const handleOnClose = () => {
    setWasOpened(false);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        id="date-picker-dialog"
        variant="inline"
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        autoOk={true}
        onOpen={handleOnOpen}
        onClose={handleOnClose}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I edited it to handle this case, but it seems worse and more hacky. Don't think I'd recommend, since it only handles the case where the picker is opened, not other cases where you may set the date with code. It may be possible to genericize the `wasOpened` state, though. Others may have better suggestions.

Comment: actually there is a eventHandler called onAccept in which I'll pass the setSelectedDate and can leave the undefined return for onChange